# Can one force randomness in a sample?

Tags: sampling, survey, randomness

I recently spoke to a large qualitative analysis company who were working on in-depth analysis of the potential customers of train company. I asked them how they chose the people to include in their sample, they said, that they picked them at random from list of people in the region, but they also said that had predefined criteria, that the sample needed have equal distribution of both genders as in the region, and similarly for ethnicity, income, education and so on. I asked them whether they believed that the list they picked from was biased, but this was not the reason, it was rather to make the sample more random. Does this make sense, or do they risk interfering with the randomness, and hence make it less random? Their sample was around 100 people, but I am interested in an answer also for very few people.

Comment: You might be interested in the thoughts at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8371/do-confidence-intervals-apply-to-quota-sampling, David.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The procedure you describe here is known as [quota sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28statistics%29#Quota_sampling). This is a non-ramdom sampling method. The procedure is frequently used in situations when there is no sampling frame available. In such a situation it provides a convenient and cheap way to draw a sample.

[Stratified sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28statistics%29#Stratified_sampling) is different. In stratified sampling the population is divided into a certain number of non-overlapping sub-populations, and each population is sampled independently. Or to put it differently, the sampling rate varies between the sub-populations.

Example: To draw a simple random sample from a group, you apply a uniform sampling rate to a population, say 10%. In stratified sampling you split the populations into two groups, say rural and urban. For each group you apply a different sampling rate, e.g. 5% for the urban population and 20% for the rural population.

Answer (score 3):

It might be easy to make the mistake (if you are careless) and interpret it as stratified sampling instead of quota sampling. As whuber pointed out in the comments below, stratified sampling requires the the partitioning of the population into groups BEFORE sampling.

"This is known as stratified sampling. It does not make it "less random" than simple random sampling.

For smaller samples, it is actually more appropriate. With simple random sampling, your samples are more likely to over-represent a category of the population."

Comment: It *is* a nonrandom method, but it may succeed in making the sample just as representative of the population, or more so, than simple random sampling would.

Comment: @rolando Yes, but if the data are subsequently analyzed as if they were from a random sample, they will usually be biased.

Comment: King, requiring an equal distribution of attributes in a population (in some unstated way) does not appear to be what is usually meant by "stratified sampling."  In [stratified sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling), the partitioning of the population into groups ("strata") occurs *before* the sampling procedure is applied.  The present situation appears to be an informal one without any explicit frame for the strata.  Although subtle, this distinction is important.

Comment: whuber, thanks for the explanation! 'before' makes everything clearer to me now.

Comment: To people more familiar with the site: Should I keep this answer here or delete it? It doesn't feel right to bury the comments which may be helpful to others.

Comment: You have options, King.  A good one is to update your reply.  If that makes any of the comments irrelevant (and a moderator notices), they will be deleted so as not to confuse future readers.  In that way we improve the content and its presentation.  Another option is to delete the reply, but as you indicate, that might be less helpful than the first option.